# Is it possible to create a Craft boilerplate out of a project.yaml file?

Tags: projectconfig

I have setup a boilerplate for Craft sites with a homepage Single setup, plugins installed, common field types setup and a few other jobs I have to do every single time I start a new project.

I was wondering if this is something I can safely turn into a CraftCMS boilerplate?

In an ideal world it's something I'd keep in Git and when I start a new project in 3 months time or whatever it may be, I can copy this `project.yaml` into my new project and I'm an hour or so ahead of where I would be.

I know technically I probably could, but I'd like some advice on whether this is something I should or should not be doing.

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have just setup a Craft 3 boilerplate and got it working great. So yeah... this does work.

Comment: did you have to sync changes after first install or did the yaml file automatically get applied?